# Do I *need* to execute `parent::_construct()`?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have a class `A`, with a bunch of classes that extend from `A` (e.g. `AA`, `AB`, `AC`, `AD`). These "sub-classes" are all called from `A`'s __contruct method.

In PhpStorm on e.g. `AA` I'm getting a warning on the `__construct` saying: "Missing parent constructor call". Adding `parent:__contruct` however obviously causes a loop in which classes keep on getting initialised

Can I safely ignore (and disable) this warning, or is it bad practise what I'm doing?

Comment: A class should never actively know about classes that extend it, not only because this creates logical loops. Rethink your entire structure.

Comment: Isn't this a good fit for the Factory pattern?

Comment: @deceze I think you are right :-) It feels a bit crooked to me, but on the other hand it does keep code a bit more together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm inclined to say you shouldn't be instantiating subclasses from the parent class's constructor.

I would suggest something more like:

```
class A {
    public static function generate() {
        // current "constructor" code here
    }
}
```

That can include `new A` and then attaching a `new AA` to that instance, and this will avoid the "loop".

Comment: It didn't feel very nice to me also. And then I should rather after `$A = new \NS\A` execute `$A->generate()`?

Comment: `\NS\A::generate()` since it's a static method.

Comment: Uhm, yes, that is what I meant ;-)